# Debugging url in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

New to javascript. I'm trying to do a quaternary operation where if the end of the url is a number, than show a button.

```
{console.log(this.urlPersonId)}
{!isNaN(parseInt(this.urlPersonId)) === true ?
    <Button size="sm" variant="outline-success"
            onClick={this.addPersonToHouse.bind(this.urlPersonId, house.HouseId)}>Add</Button>
    :
    <Link>no stuff</Link>
}
```

And in the constructor I have

```
this.state = {
    urlPersonId: window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
    houses: [],
    currentPage: 1,
    housesPerPage: 5
};
```

But when my url ends with a number it still shows a link with "no stuff". My question is, how do I debug the program so I can see what's in `urlPersonId`?

Comment: you can use react-router-dom to declare routes and make final string as param. You can fetch those params to your current page and check if that param is a number or not. check https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params.

Comment: @Karrthik I have `<Route path={"/addPersonToHouse/:personId"} exact component={HouseList}/>`, but where do I make a `let` value? In the constructor? Or in the `render()`?

Comment: you can get that in constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so basically I put `this.personId` in when it was supposed to be `this.state.personId`.

*The more you know* :p

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hooks you can use

```
 let { personId } = useParams();
```

if you are using class component you can do

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { match: {
       params: { personId }
        }
    } = props;
    this.state = {
       personId = personId
    }
 }
```

And then you can use this.state.personId everywhere you need in the component.